# O que e quais são os tipos de ambiente de desenvolvimento?

Tags: terminologia, engenharia-de-software, independente-de-linguagem

Ocasionalmente vejo algo deste gênero em diversos projetos:

```
env: 'production'
```

O que é isso? Quais são as outras opções convencionais (além de "production") e para que serve?

Por que devo usar isso na minha aplicação?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Normalmente você encontra pelo menos 2 ambientes de desenvolvimento:

- desenvolvimento
- produção

Dependendo da criatividade e da burocracia envolvida no processo, você pode ter outros ambientes:

- desenvolvimento
- teste (*)
- homologação
- beta
- produção

> (*): aqui destacando o teste e separando do desenvolvimento, pois muitas vezes o ambiente de desenvolvimento o próprio programador viciou ele. Pode ser colocando dados artificiais para prosseguir na tarefa ou normalizando dados selvagens para dados comportados e controlados. O ambiente de teste nesse caso é de responsabilidade do setor de testes/qualidade/QA, que mantém os dados mais próximos possíveis da selvageria de produção (ou o forçam para um tipo específico de selvageria para testar algum aspecto).

Vou focar no resto da resposta apenas na divisão mais notória: desenvolvimento e produção.

### Por que separar?

Para que o desenvolvedor possa quebrá-lo. Sem medo. Para que seja sua caixinha de areia e ele possa fazer o que quiser ou precisar sem se preocupar com consequências.

O ambiente de produção é um lugar sensível. Normalmente se costuma dizer que "não se faz teste em produção", e essa frase é verdade quase sempre.

No meu caso, eu trabalho com um sistema de vendas. Para fazer alguma mudança que o cliente pediu para acrescentar alguma regra de venda, eu preciso realizar uma venda. Posso fazer boa parte do que eu quero e testar essas mudanças e não salvar o pedido de venda no último instante. Mas nem sempre é possível.

Imagine o seguinte cenário:

- eu preciso que o pedido fique pendente para clientes que estejam com títulos atrasados; cada grupo de clientes terá um limite de atraso distinto.

Eu só posso garantir que o pedido para o cliente do grupo "bom pagador" que está atrasado a 90 dias ficará pendente se eu fizer o pedido, salvar e conferir. Agora, imagina que eu ainda estou desenvolvendo o sistema e por um bug o pedido não ficou pendente. Isso significa que automaticamente esse pedido será processado e emitido para o cliente. Quando o pedido chegar na porta do cliente, ele falará que não fez esse pedido e mandará voltar.

Além do incômodo do frete de ida e volta das mercadorias, ainda terei causado um estresse desnecessário entre o vendedor e o cliente. No ambiente de teste, esse pedido não seria processado, mesmo por bug. Portanto, nunca iria parar na porta dele. Não teria estresse para ninguém e eu posso desenvolver tranquilamente sem me preocupar se vou causar prejuízo a alguém (além das eventuais atrasos nas entregas).

Outra situação que pode acontecer, também, e que geraria dor de cabeças. Imagina que você resolveu mudar a infraestrutura do sistema para usar um ORM, que precisou fazer isso para dar maior manutenabilidade no sistema. Você aplicou inicialmente a forma mais ingênua disso, e não percebeu que estava verificando quais objetos dentro de 1.000.000 se relacionavam a outros 1.000.000 de objetos, então o sistema precisou testar todas as possibilidades para montar o mapeamento. Dá para ver que esse mapeamento possível ocupa mais do que 10 bilhões de itens (ocupa na verdade 10^12, um trilhão de itens). E você fez tudo isso, para cada mapeamento distinto desses 1 trilhão, fazendo uma consulta no banco. Seu banco de dados teria de lidar com 1 trilhão de consultas, o que é **muito**. Se seu banco for muito bom e em 100% da capacidade atender 1 bilhão de requisições por segundo, ainda seria necessário esperar mais ou menos 20 minutos até ele estar disponível para quem usa ele em produção. Você sem querer fez um ataque de negação de serviço ao seu servidor, e seus usuários ficaram sem entender por um terço de hora o que estava de fato acontecendo.

### Quando devo usar esses ambientes?

Se você está desenvolvendo algo, então é sinal que você deve selecionar o ambiente de "desenvolvimento". Isso deveria ser óbvio.

Se você já fechou o seu produto e está entregando ele para o cliente, então selecione que está em produção.

Se você usar outros ambientes (como a escala de cinco ambientes que eu mencionei), então o responsável por colocar no ar essas coisas sabe qual ambiente usar em cada situação.

### De quem é a responsabilidade de configurar isso?

Essa responsabilidade cabe ao setor de "operações". Desenvolvedores não deveriam mexer nisso (exceto para "testar em produção", e isso deve ser feito com todo o carinho do mundo). O desenvolvedor deveria colocar para desenvolvimento e esquecer sobre a existência disso em... quase todos os casos que não envolvam bugs?

Claro, a filosofia DevOps é para deixar desenvolvimento e produção mais próximos. Mas é bom separar quem é quem. Por exemplo, o Jefferson desenvolvedor gosta de desbravar e tentar algoritmos e técnicas inovadoras para resolver seus problemas, mas o Jefferson de operações gosta que as coisas tenham uma evolução mais paulatina e controlada, mais garantida e segura. O conflito interno entre meus dois Jeffersons fazem com que eu tente tomar uma decisão equilibrada.

> O Jefferson desenvolvedor é mais teimoso e costuma vencer

### Ele sempre apresenta a separação desse jeito?

Não, nem sempre é assim. Onde trabalho, temos os arquivos `jdbc-dev.properties`, `jdbc-prod.properties`. Em algum lugar da inclusão de dependências é apontado qual dessas configurações do banco de dados é de fato usada naquele momento, apontando para o nome do arquivo.

### Devo usar na minha aplicação?

Talvez. Provavelmente. Pelos motivos acima mencionados. Agora, saiba que isso é uma burocracia, que isso aumenta a segurança do desenvolvimento em detrimento de alguma velocidade (possivelmente). Então, se você está fazendo isso só para desenvolver seu portfólio, ou só para estudos, não sei se vale a pena perder um tempinho com isso.

Comment: @lffg poderia ir mais longe, mas acho que fugiria do foco principal =] Resolvi deixar assim, "sucinto" porém completo o suficiente

Comment: Um exemplo bem básico da distinção entre desenvolvimento e produção é poder começar uma manutenção de código às 17:30 de um dia, terminar no outro, sem se preocupar em gerar erro de sintaxe no sistema funcionando.